# Why am I getting ReferenceError: React is not defined?

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a React Native application. I want to add unit tests with Jest. When I run `yarn test`, I get the following error:

```
FAIL  ./App.test.tsx
● app › can render snapshot

ReferenceError: React is not defined

   5 | describe("app", () => {
   6 |   it("can render snapshot", () => {
>  7 |     const tree = renderer.create(<App />);
     |                                  ^
   8 |     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
   9 |   });
  10 | });
```

Here's my `App.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsmobile from "./src/aws-exports";
import AppContainer from "./src/navigation/index";

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppContainer />
  );
};
```

Here's what I have in my `App.test.tsx`:

```js
import "react-native";
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import App from "./App";

describe("app", () => {
  it("can render snapshot", () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And, here's my `jest.config.js`:

```js
// jest.config.js
const {defaults: tsjPreset} = require("ts-jest/presets");

module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  preset: "react-native",
  transform: {
    ...tsjPreset.transform,
    "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      babelConfig: true,
    },
  },
  // This is the only part which you can keep
  // from the above linked tutorial's config:
  cacheDirectory: ".jest/cache",
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "ios.js",
    "native.js",
    "js",
    "json",
    "jsx",
    "node",
    "ios.ts",
    "native.ts",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
  ],
};
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's my `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/react-native/).

Comment: Does it work with `esModuleInterop: true` in tsconfig.json?

Comment: No, `esModuleInterop` is set to `true` already.

Comment: Try `const tree = renderer.create(React.createElement(App))` see if error goes away?

Comment: Do you also have a babel config ? It is often used to make jest work with React...

Comment: @ataravati which method did you use to create the TS app? You have to also `import 'react-native'` **before** `react-test-renderer` as you can see in the [`react-native/template/__tests__/App-test.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f2ffa0313980f05b9d417e957c3539e4e6495b9f/template/__tests__/App-test.js#L5) template test file.

Comment: @ChristosLytras I added `import 'react-native';` as you said, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Orlyyn, yes, I do. I'll update my question.

Comment: @hackape No, that doesn't work. It gives me another error: `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`.

Comment: By the way, I decided not to use `ts-jest`. I came up with another configuration without ts-jest that works.

Comment: @ataravati can you please tell me which method did you use to scaffold you TS React project? Is it `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`?

Comment: @ChristosLytras `npx react-native init my-app —template react-native-template-typescript`

Comment: @ataravati can you please add contents of your `package.json` to the question? If you have used `npx react-native init my-app —template react-native-template-typescript` you didn't have to do anything else to have Jest working with typescript, neither install `ts-jest` or create a `jest.setup.js` file because it's working out of the box.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Yes, as I mentioned in an earlier comment, that’s what I ended up doing. I removed ts-jest, and now everything is working.

Comment: @ataravati didn't see that comment. Nice you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

For me setting the next config fixed the issue:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleDirectories: ['./node_modules', 'src'],
  cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/tests/SvgStub.js'
  },
  setupFiles: ['./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/packages/'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules'],
}
```

Sources: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11591#issuecomment-899508417